# How to get Ajax working on server with medium trust

Tags: c#, .net, ajax

I have an ASP.NET app with some AJAX stuff that runs perfectly on my dev machine, but when I try to run on the server, the pages that have the ToolkitScriptManager gives the following error: 
"Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information." 
in the satck trace it says: 
"[ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.]" 
and 
"[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerConfig' threw an exception.]".
The thing is, this app is hosted in a hosting company (uolhost.com) so I don't have access to the IIS configuration, all I know is that it has the trust level set to medium. I tried to add `<trust level="Full" />` in my web.config file, but then it gives me the next error: "This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using  from an inherited configuration file."
I have referenced ajax on the top of the pages as follows:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

My web.config file is bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <location path="">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Default.aspx" timeout="15" />
    </authentication>

    <compilation targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime/>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
        <add assembly="JuiceUI" namespace="Juice" tagPrefix="juice"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=mydb;Data Source=mydatasource"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.4" newVersion="2.1.0.4"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="HtmlAgilityPack" publicKeyToken="bd319b19eaf3b43a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.4.9.0" newVersion="1.4.9.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Does anybody can figure out if the problem is really with the trust level on the server? If it is, is there any work around for that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I had a similar problem. All I can do with your example is guess but I don't think it has any thing to do with the trust level...check that there is only one instance of the script manager in the page that is throwing the error. I have also come across this type of error if a JavaScript library like jQuery is referenced more than once in the same page. Can you post more of the code that's throwing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is due to trust level, AjaxControlToolkit requires full trust level, and if you are on shared server this setting is done in machine.config which is in control of hosting site. Call your hosting support and tell them to apply full trust to your domain.

Comment: Thanks Sagar for the answer. You are right, the problem is with the trus level as I supposed it could be. Unfortunately the hosting suport says they can't apply full trust to my domain for security resasons... So I ended up removing all ajax from my app.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks BillRuhl for the answer.
Yes, the script manager is referenced just once in each page that uses it.
The aspx page that throws the error has the following code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CadLinha.aspx.cs" Inherits="Fricave.CadLinha" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <h2>Cadastro de Linha de produtos</h2>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="plnCadastro" Visible="true" Width="938px">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 44px; width: 610px;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboLinha" runat="server" CssClass="radiusInput" AutoPostBack="true" Height="26px" Width="600px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboLinha_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDescricao" CssClass="RequiredField" ErrorMessage="Informe o cadastro a ser cancelado." ValidationGroup="Cancelar"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 220px; height: 44px;">
                    <asp:Image ID="imgCancelado" ImageUrl="Images/Cancelado.png" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <ul>
            <li style="width: 550px; height: 100px;">
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Descrição"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescricao" runat="server" CssClass="radiusInput" Width="500px" AutoPostBack="True" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDescricao" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDescricao" CssClass="RequiredField" ErrorMessage="Preencha a descrição." SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="Salvar"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </li>
            <li style="vertical-align: top; height: 100px;">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Comissão</legend>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Receber"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtReceber" runat="server" CssClass="radiusInput" Width="50px" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtComissoes_TextChanged">0,00</asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Pagar"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPagar" runat="server" CssClass="radiusInput" Width="50px" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtComissoes_TextChanged" ControlToValidate="txtPagar">0,00</asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Button ID="btnSalvar" CssClass="btnSave btn" runat="server" Text="Salvar" OnClick="btnSalvar_Click" ValidationGroup="Salvar" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnNovo" CssClass="btnNew btn" runat="server" Text="Novo" OnClick="btnNovo_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnCancelar" CssClass="btnCancel btn" runat="server" Text="Cancelar" OnClick="btnCancelar_Click" ValidationGroup="Cancelar" />

</asp:Content>
```

The error page when run on the server says:

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the
>   LoaderExceptions property for more information.

Error in line 7:

```
Line 5:  <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server"> 
Line 6:   
Line 7: <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"> </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager> 
Line 8: <h2>Cadastro de Linha de produtos</h2> 
Line 9: <asp:Panel  runat="server" ID="plnCadastro" Visible="true" Width="938px">
```

Stack Trace:

> [ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the
>   requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more
>   information.]
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes() +4
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() +70
>   AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerConfig..cctor() +68
>
> [TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerConfig' threw an exception.]
>   AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager..ctor() +62
>   ASP.cadlinha_aspx.__BuildControlToolkitScriptManager1() in
>   e:\home\ssdsistema1\ssdsistemas.com.br\web\LitoralAlimentos\CadLinha.aspx:7
>   ASP.cadlinha_aspx.__BuildControlContent2(Control __ctrl) in
>   e:\home\ssdsistema1\ssdsistemas.com.br\web\LitoralAlimentos\CadLinha.aspx:5
>   System.Web.UI.CompiledTemplateBuilder.InstantiateIn(Control container)
>   +10    System.Web.UI.MasterPage.InstantiateInContentPlaceHolder(Control
>   contentPlaceHolder, ITemplate template) +88
>   ASP.site1_master.__BuildControlMainContent() +113
>   ASP.site1_master.__BuildControlfrmMaster() +283
>   ASP.site1_master.__BuildControlTree(site1_master __ctrl) +196
>   ASP.site1_master.FrameworkInitialize() +37
>   System.Web.UI.UserControl.InitializeAsUserControlInternal() +32
>   System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner,
>   HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary
>   contentTemplateCollection) +655    System.Web.UI.Page.get_Master() +54
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage() +14
>   System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() +45
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +335